# Бесконечное каррирование

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код. Мне надо переписать его так чтобы он например при вызове `console.log(add(1)(2)(3))` вернул число 6 и без пустых скобок в конце

```js
const add = (a) => {
  let sum = a;
  const func = b => {
    if (b) {
      sum += b;
      return func;
    } else {
      return sum;
    }
  };
  return func;
};
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или вы неверно поняли задание или вы неверно нам его изложили.

Answer (score 3):

Ситуация такая, что функция в любом случае должна возвращаться. Но как понять, что это последний вызов в цепочке? **Никак!**

Тут фишка в другом: `console.log` неявно вызывает метод `toString`, который можно перезаписать

Есть метод `valueOf`, который используется, когда значение приводится к числу

```js
const add = (a = 0) => {
  let sum = a;
  const func = (b = 0) => {
    sum += b;
    return func;
  };

  func.toString = () => sum // Переопределяем метод toString
  func.valueOf = () => sum // Перезаписываем valueOf

  return func;
};


console.log(add(1)(1)(1)(7));
console.log(add(1)(2)(3));
console.log(add(0)(0)(0)(1)()()()(1)); // вызов с пустыми скобками, то же что и вызов с нулем

// Фокусы с valueOf
console.log(add(1)(1) + add(5)(3));
console.log(add(1) + add() + add(9));
```

Comment: В общем случае данное решение бесполезно (к тому же вызов `add(1)(2)(3)` не возвращает число 6). Как вы думаете, мы верно поняли задание ТС?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а где написано, что он должно возвращать число? Кажется, ТС явно указал, что `console.log` должно выводить число, на что решение и было

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я описал в ответе про неявный вызов `toString`, на самом деле задание это часто на собесах встречается, возможно ТС встретил его в задачнике ( я сам с таким вопросом сталкивался, условие как раз было про `console.log` )

Comment: Ещё есть `valueOf`. Кмк, он семантически лучше подходит.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, можно же `let sum = +add(1)(2)(3);`

Comment: @vp_arth можно по разному. Можно и `Number(add(1)(2)(3))`. Я хотел донести мысль, что данное решение бесполезное, с практической точки зрения. Хотя, если  такое задают на собеседовании, я бы поостерегся работать в такой компании.

Comment: Бесполезно не решение, а задание)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а что плохого в задаче? Кроме концепта каррирования/замыкания, можно еще узнать, знает ли человек про внутренние механизмы движка. Никто не знает, что может понадобиться

Comment: @vp_arth в задании тоже мало смысла. Но в таком задании может быть нормальное решение. Но и задание и решение бессмысленные))

Comment: @ThisMan плохо в задаче то, что оно сферическое в вакууме :-) Это как напишите, когда `a==1 && a==2 && a==3` будет `true`. Тестовые задания на собеседованиях должны проверять компетенции, а не умение писать сложночитаемый\ненужный код.

Comment: https://imgur.com/fyOTvkz.png